# How to update a List<(T, T, T)> in C#

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I have the following list and would like to update it.

```cs
List<(ulong channel, ulong user, object answer)> questions = 
    Globals.Discord.Interactive.Questions;
```

I tried using some `LINQ` but couldn't get it to work.

```cs
questions.Find(x => x.channel == channel.Id).answer = null;
```

Indexes don't seem possible to use.

```cs
questions[questions.FindIndex(x => x.channel == channel.Id)].answer = null;
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is first find the `Index` to update, use that `Index` to get the Tuple out, then use that `Index` again to provide the list with the updated Tuple.

Something like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var questions = new List<(ulong channel, ulong user, object answer)>
    {
        (1, 1, 1),
        (2, 2, 2),
        (3, 3, 3),
        (4, 4, 4)
    };

    foreach (var (channel, user, answer) in questions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(answer);
    }

    var channel3Index = questions.FindIndex((obj) => obj.channel == 3);
    if (channel3Index > -1)
    {
        var question = questions[channel3Index];
        question.answer = 666;
        questions[channel3Index] = question;
    }

    foreach (var (channel, user, answer) in questions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(answer);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The reason why you have to first update it, then replace it with the existing one is because you are using ValueTuples, which are value types. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

**Edit**:
If you don't want to use a value type in your List, use a reference type. A simple class will do.

```
  class Program
    {
        public class Question
        {
            public ulong Channel { get; set; }

            public ulong User { get; set; }

            public Object Answer { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var questions = new List<Question>
            {
                new Question
                {
                    Channel = 1,
                    User = 1,
                    Answer = 1
                },
                new Question
                {
                    Channel = 2,
                    User = 2,
                    Answer = 2
                },
                new Question
                {
                    Channel = 3,
                    User = 3,
                    Answer = 3
                },
            };

            foreach (var question in questions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(question.Answer);
            }

            var channel3Index = questions.FindIndex((obj) => obj.Channel == 3);
            if (channel3Index > -1)
            {
                questions[channel3Index].Answer = 666;
            }

            foreach (var question in questions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(question.Answer);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Do you think there would be something better/easier to use than a ValueTuples List here?

Comment: @Laiteux , please note that [FindIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?view=netframework-4.8) will transform only the first answer. from your domain, I suppose, you might have many answers from different users on the same channel.

Comment: @Fenixil My code is handling that possibility, no worries ;) Thanks tho!

Answer (score 1):

You can use functional like transformation on the collections with the immutable types, for example using pattern matching:

```
var data = new List<(ulong channel, ulong user, object answer)>() {
  (1, 2, "a1"), 
  (4, 5, "a2") 
};

data.Select(x =>
{
    switch (x)
    {
        case var z when z.channel == 1: return (z.channel, z.user, null);
        default: return x;
    }
});
```

Please note, that you don't mutate existing collection, but create `IEnumerable` which will transform it. You may materialize it by calling `.ToList().AsReadOnly()` for example.

If you prefer more imperative way, then you can just iterate over the collection and mutate it.

```
var data = new (ulong channel, ulong user, object answer)[] {
    (1, 2, "a1"),
    (4, 5, "a2")
};
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    if (data[i].channel == 1)
        data[i].answer = null;
```

One interesting thing in this example is that you don't need to create a new tuple and replace it in the array: when you access structure in the array by index it is not cloned, so you can mutate it. That is specific only to the array and will not work with the `List`.